# How detailed can baked textures go?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, baking

I have modelled a coat here, and using a few point lights and some flat colors in photoshop, i was able to bake the texture as seen on the picture. However i question if it's possible to create even more layers of detail like reflections, subsurface scattering and so on, making a more detailed texture.

Do node setups carry onto the baking in the first place? I haven't learned how to do materials in blender mainly because i assume they only serve a purpose within blender and that i can't really have that fancy resulting texture bake into my model in the end.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). You can bake any node setup into a texture. Are you asking how to export Blender materials into separate texture maps like Roughness, Metalness, etc?

Comment: Oh, you can!? I'll start looking into nodes. I'm not sure how to do roughness or metallic textures, but that might be too long to answer in this question.